# Paste path into File Open/Save Dialog?

Tags: file, shortcut, keybindings

How do I paste a file path into a standard file open/save dialog?

I have googled this and found articles that say that the normal <kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> will work, however it does not work for me.

I'm running Mac OS 10.10.2 with minimal system customizations.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In your open/save window, press <kbd>Cmd-Shift-G</kbd> to open a window where you can paste the path.

This also works in Finder.

Comment: I can do cmd-shift-g in an open dialog and a dialog in a dialog pops up, "Go to the folder". I have a text field, but copy/paste keys are disabled and do not work.

Comment: paste Works for me into the "Go to the folder:" field? What are you tring to copy?   In my test I was able to copy paste something like /Users/devuser

Comment: @clay you cannot use ⌘+V to paste into dialog boxes, but if you right-click there is a paste in the popup menu.

Comment: Thank you @Milliways. I can do right-click->Paste, but ⌘+V does not work as was said.

Comment: @clay Obviously the information you found is wrong. the keyboard shortcuts do not work in system dialog boxes in any program. I find this mildly annoying in my own programs, but not so annoying that it is worth writing my own dialogs.

Comment: That is weird. I am running OSX 10.9.5 and a am able to use ⌘+V in the dialog that pops up after I pressing ⌘+[shift]+[G].